# Webkit-overflow-scrolling property makes DIV to ignore z-index value

Tags: css, webkit, z-index

When I use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` for outer DIV wrapper it starts to ignore `z-index` property for this wrapper. Production code https://info-kurs.com/auction (`div.hrz-scroll` - the code where I experienced this issue). I found a way to achieve my goal with negative margin. But I need to figure out why does this property makes to ignore z-index?

Comment: Read this [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Comment: @olegoriginal OMG! Thank you!